# Question on the Raabe's test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Bartle - Real analysis

> Raabe's Test
>
> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$
>
> If there exists $a>1$ and $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq K$, $\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|\leq 1-\frac{a}{n}$, then $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely.
>
> If there exists $a\leq 1$ and $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq K$, $\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|\geq 1-\frac{a}{n}$, then $\sum x_n$ does not converge absolutely.

I have reformulated above statement as follows, to make it easy to memorize.

> If $\limsup \limits_{n\to\infty} n\left(\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| -1\right) <-1$, then $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely.
>
> If $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left[n\geq N \Rightarrow n\left(\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| -1\right) \geq -1\right]$, then $\sum x_n$ diverges.

Is this a correct reformulation?